# Zebra Printer (P430i): How to print a bitmap with EPCL

Tags: bitmap, zebra-printers

Zebra EPCL developer manuals suggest to print a bitmap with "O" command preceding a "G" command. Syntax suggest to start a command with < ESC > and end with < CR >, but if I decorate "O" command with complementary characters and try to run on printer command's entry it always return a command error message, but if I use "G" command purely, it works! Tried the same with "O" to send the bitmap, but it never works.

```
G 50 50 0 3 1 1
O 00 FF F0
```

Return: **Invalid command**.

I didn't find any sample on internet. Can someone help?